# Worksheets.Item / Worksheet.Cells properties working in unexpected way

Tags: excel, powershell, etl

**Edit: Ignore - this is actually behaving this way because of some code outside the scope of this script. My mistake. I just submitted a request to close this post.**

I have a simple PowerShell script that is supposed to delete the first line from an Excel `.xls` file.

My Script is as follows:

```
$file = $args[0]


    # Start Excel, hide window
    $excel = new-object -com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file) # Open the file
    $workbook.CheckCompatibility = $False
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item("Acutal Worksheet") # Select appropriate worksheet
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row

    $workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook and save changes
    $excel.quit() # Quit Excel
    [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) # Release COM
```

When I run this, the PoSh script finishes clean, but when I open the Workbook, I notice that the first **two** rows have been deleted. I only want the first row to be deleted.

Now, when I run the script with a worksheet name that **does not exist in the workbook**, the script throws the following error **and when I open the Workbook, only the first row has been deleted from the target worksheet.** Note: There is only a single worksheet within the workbook. It is producing my desired outcome, but this is ugly and I need to implement something that makes sense to me. What needs to be changed in order for it to work when I specify the correct Worksheet name?

Example of script with name that does not exist in workbook:

```
$file = $args[0]


    # Start Excel, hide window
    $excel = new-object -com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file) # Open the file
    $workbook.CheckCompatibility = $False
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item("WRONG_NAME") # Select appropriate worksheet
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row

    $workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook and save changes
    $excel.quit() # Quit Excel
    [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) # Release COM
```

Error I get from running this:

```
Exception getting "Item": "Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (
DISP_E_BADINDEX))"
At I:\path\ps_myScript.ps1:10 char:35
+     $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item <<<< ("WRONG_NAME") # Select appropriate works
heet
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], GetValueInvocationExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterParameterizedPropertyGetValu
   eTI

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At I:\path\ps_myScript.ps1:11 char:28
+     [void]$sheet.Cells.Item <<<< (1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first
 row
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce the issue. Your code was working fine for me when I try. Here is a link to the image with before and after screens: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/uLbSIPn.png)

However, the `Delete` method accepts an argument for deciding how to shift and replace the deleted cells. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.delete%28v=office.11%29.aspx) says, `if this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range.`, so I am wondering if this could be the cause of the issues you are facing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that actually is caused by faulty code outside of the scope of the powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 1 sheet skip the whole `$Sheet=` line and just change the next line to:

```
[void]$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete()# Delete the first row
```

I use something very similar in a script of mine. I think I use $null= instead of [void], and Item(2, 1) to do the second row instead of the first, but it should work the same.

Comment: +1 for contributing. I tried this, but unfortunately, the script is still deleting the first 2 rows.

Comment: Ignore - this is actually behaving this way because of some code outside the scope of this script. My mistake. I just submitted a request to close this post.